# k8s coredns pods showing CrashLoopBackOff due to property max_concurrent

Tags: coredns

I believe this issue raised after upgraded k8s to 1.19 from 1.18. I didn't checked after upgraded the cluster.

```
k8scka@master:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-7dbc97f587-dfbwl   1/1     Running            0          8d
calico-node-jkgwv                          1/1     Running            0          10d
calico-node-wkncc                          1/1     Running            0          10d
coredns-66bff467f8-frh49                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2093       7d10h
coredns-66bff467f8-wlb22                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2092       7d10h
etcd-master                                1/1     Running            0          8d
kube-apiserver-master                      1/1     Running            0          8d
kube-controller-manager-master             1/1     Running            0          8d
kube-proxy-ljz55                           1/1     Running            0          8d
kube-proxy-w8nvg                           1/1     Running            0          8d
kube-scheduler-master                      1/1     Running            0          8d
k8scka@master:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

else,
we can Upgrade the coredns to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

verified the coredns CM and removed the property **max_concurrent**.
automatically issue resolved.

Comment: [Corresponding github issue.](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/4362)